# Spring batch stopping after one iteration

Tags: spring-batch

I have a strange behavior with spring batch that stop iterating after one read/write.

I have a chunk  step:

```
    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1000;

    @Bean
    public Step compareExtractDataStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("compareExtractDataStep")
            .<CarExtract, ComparisonResult>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
            .reader(readAllCarExtract(extractCarDao))
            .processor(getAndCompareWithExternData())
            .writer(saveComparisonResult())
            .build();
    } 

    @Bean
    public CarExtract readAllCarExtract(CarExtract extractCarDao){
        return new CarExtract(extractCarDao);
    }

    @Bean
    public GetAndCompareWithExternData getAndCompareWithExternData() {
        return new GetAndCompareWithExternData();
    }

    @Bean
    public ComparisonResultWriter saveComparisonResult() {
        return new ComparisonResultWriter();
    }
```

Where the reader is

```
public class ExtractCarReader extends RepositoryItemReader<CarExtract> {
   

    public ExtractCarReader (CarExtractDao carExtractDao, int chunkSize) {
        super();
        this.setPageSize(chunkSize);
        this.setSort(sortCarExtract());
        this.setRepository(carExtractDao);
        this.setMethodName("findAll");
    }
    
    private Map<String, Sort.Direction> sortCarExtract() {
        final HashMap<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
        sorts.put("plate", Sort.Direction.ASC);
        return sorts;
    }

}
```

Where the processor is

```
public class GetAndCompareWithExternData implements ItemProcessor<CarExtract, ComparisonResult> {

 @Override
    public ComparisonResult process(CarExtract car) throws Exception {
        ComparisonResult comparisonResult = new ComparisonResult(car.getCarKey());

        Optional<ExternalCarData> carExternal = externalCarDataDAO.findByTransactionKey(car.getCarKey().getVehicleLicensePlate());

        try{
                assertEquals(FLEET_MSG,car.getFleetVehicleIndicator(), carExternal.getFleetVehicleIndicator());
//...

        }catch (AsssertionException error){
                comparisonResult.setStatus(ERROR);
                comparisonResult.setMessage(error.getMessage());
                return comparisonResult;
        }

        comparisonResult.setStatus(SUCCESS);
        return comparisonResult;
//...
```

Where the writer is

```
public class ComparisonResultWriter implements ItemWriter<ComparisonResult> {

    @Autowired
    private ComparisonResultService comparisonResultService;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends ComparisonResult> list) {
        for(ComparisonResult result: list){
            comparisonResultService.save(result);
        }
    }
}
```

But the batch stop after one select.
And when I run the select from hibernate logs I have plenty of results.
May you help me to solve this mystery please ?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 1000 items in the datasource? How are you running jobs? Have you tried to make the reader `@StepScope`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: the spring batch reader stop when it read null values in the key.
And because my JPA composit key (@EmbeddedId) was containing sometimes null value it was stopping.

I understand because I added more hibernate logs thanks to

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE"/>
```

where I saw that my chunk was well selected but the second row had a null in the key.

By playing also with the sorting, it gave me a hint because I didn't had always the same result.